# Genitive S ... in the phrase with 'lookalike'

Tags: grammar

Should the word before the word 'lookalike' have an apostrophe or not? In the same dictionary I found these:

> https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/lookalike

Coming towards him, big smile freezing fast, was this **Julie Christie lookalike** in Fringed Suede.

**Mao lookalikes** also dominate the cinema.

**Victoria's lookalike** sister Louise, 24, arrived with a male pal who was the image of Becks.

Comment: You normally need a *determiner* before ***lookalike***. For example, *It's hard to tell the difference between **the** lookalike and the real Mao.* But *possessives* count as determiners in this context, so *It's hard to tell the difference between Mao and **his** lookalike* (and your ***Victoria's lookalike*** example) are both fine.

Comment: The question is about the use of bare "<noun> + lookalike".  It is normal use, and there is no determiner.   @Michael Harvey's answer below is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the noun 'lookalike' two ways:

1. After a noun (no possessive 's')

My wife is a Marilyn Monroe lookalike
His car is a Fiat 600 lookalike

2. After a noun (possessive 's')

Marilyn Monroe's lookalike, Jane Harvey, is my wife.
The Fiat 600's lookalike, the Jones 600, is a nice car.

Comment: To explain this a little bit, it's the use of"Marilyn Monroe" that changes, not the use of "lookalike".   Here, the actress' name is an *attributive noun* that functions as an adjective.   The use is not much different from speaking about "an *apartment building*" or a "cashmere sweater".

Comment: Yes, any number of nouns could come after a name like Julie Christie: cardboard cutout, poster, fan, etc.